# Convert string to dict key object for reference/assignment

Tags: python, dynamic

Suppose I have a function that returns a dictionary key name (as string). Is there a way i can convert it to key object? I tried `sys.intern` but it doesn't help.

```
def myDictstring():
    return 'mydt[par[0]][par[1]]'

def myMain():
  vartemp = myDictstring() 
 
  sys.intern(vartemp) = 101
```

Comment: you could use the string as a key like so `you_dictionary = {your_key: 'value'}`
Why would you need to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

got it. Need to use eval
eval(vartemp) = {100}